# Does locking folders work at file system level or is it only for locking UI actions?

Tags: macos

Does Locking a folder prevent programs from also writing to files / creating files / deleteing files in that folder and its subfolders?

Or is it only locking UI actions?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so it would be better suited to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Amazed It's not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking via the UI does prevent other programs/processes/users from changing the folder's content, in any way.

A simple test you can run to prove it to yourself: open terminal and navigate to a folder. In Finder, click Command+I on that folder and lock it. In terminal, type `cat > test`. You'd get an error message. Unlock the folder and re-run the command in terminal - it now works.